# How to detect red laser light using open cv and get x,y coordinates

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I've been using the following code to detect red laser light and get the coordinates for it, but facing a problem in getting the accurate coordinates.

Below is the code I tried to get to a solution for my problem.

I want the accurate coordinates for the red laser light or red objects as I am using cpp code in iOS App.

---

```
cv::Mat bgr_image;
UIImageToMat(image, bgr_image);
cv::Mat hsv_image;
cv::cvtColor(bgr_image, hsv_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

cv::Mat lower_red_hue_range;
cv::Mat upper_red_hue_range;
cv::Mat allRedHue;

cv::inRange(hsv_image, cv::Scalar(0, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(10, 255, 255), lower_red_hue_range);
cv::inRange(hsv_image, cv::Scalar(160, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(179, 255, 255), upper_red_hue_range);
cv::addWeighted(lower_red_hue_range, 1.0, upper_red_hue_range, 1.0, 0.0, allRedHue);
Moments m = moments(allRedHue, true);
Point2f p = Point2f(m.m10/m.m00, m.m01/m.m00);
p == p?
dict = @{@"xPoint":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:p.x],@"yPoint":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:p.y]} :
dict = @{@"xPoint":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],@"yPoint":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]};
```

Comment: Can you upload the image you are working with?

Comment: @RickM. Here is the image, I need to detect the correct coordinate for the red laser light.

Comment: @RickM. Image URL- https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU42h.jpg

Comment: @PrincePrabhakar: You mean the _white_ spot? It seems your sensor is so oversaturated by the read laser that the energy spills over to adjacent green & blue pixels. You can't really fix that sort of hardware problem in software.

Comment: @MSalters I just need the code to find the _coordinates_ for the **spot**. Rest I can manage at my end.

Comment: Less exposure probably wouldn't hurt. As is, you can take advantage of the fact that the spot is so oversaturated. It's not the red parts you want, it's the really bright white spot -- in fact, ideally you want to get rid of all the red glow around. So, take the blue or green channel from the BGR image, and threshold it somewhere around 225 or so...

Comment: I am able to detect the red colour over grey surface but not able to detect the the red laser light colour over the white surface, any references for the issue.